# Black screen during startup causes automatic reboot

Tags: boot, grub2

On a notebook with Ubuntu 18.04.2 (x86, 32 bit) the boot process has been causing problems since a few days.

Boot problem in detail:

1. On startup no grub menu appears.
2. The dark purple background typical for Ubuntu **without** any Ubuntu logo or text appears for several seconds.
3. The screen briefly turns black and the notebook restarts automatically.
4. The grub menu appears.
5. I choose "Ubuntu".
6. Ubuntu searches for file system errors.
7. Ubuntu boots up.
8. The usual Unity 7 desktop appears after a while.

After shutting down and turning on again, the process starts again from the beginning. See [syslog](https://pastebin.com/t7EPFr9r).

What is the reason for this problem and how can it be solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding following line
`GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=text`
to `/etc/default/grub` and update grub with
`sudo update-grub`
solved the problem.

See: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1724639